# All geometry looks glitchy in viewport in Blender 2.8

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I'm using Blender 2.8 (release, not beta) for my new project and after adding some objects (just as placeholders, no complex geometry) all geometry around edges looks strange.

This however doesn't occur while looking through a camera.

I have used Blender 2.8 beta before and there wasn't this problem

[image: Glitches while not looking through the camera]

[image: Normal looking geometry through the camera]

Answer (score 0):

Check your viewport's clipping. The min value may be too small for your scene, or too large.
[image]